# does fstream read/write move file pointer

Tags: c++, fstream

This is kind of a simple question that I hope can be answered easily, do the file stream read and write operations move the pointer along? As an example:

```
cpos=10000;
for (i=0;i<20;i++) {
   dataFile.seekg(cpos+i,ios::beg);
   dataFile.read(carray[i],1);
}
```

Is it identical (logically) to:

```
dataFile.seekg(cpos,ios::beg);    
cpos=10000;
for (i=0;i<20;i++) {
    dataFile.read(carray[i],1);
}
```

In other words, does carray[] contain the same contents regardless of which method is used (I can't see the first method being efficient so I am hoping that the correct answer is yes). If so, is same behavior exhibited by write operations?

Comment: @starriet Edit rejected. Your edit destroyed the meaning of the post. Don't do that. The question is about seeking and not seeking, and removing the seek makes it meaningless. Read it before acting.

Comment: @user207421 You reverted it back to the mistakenly coded version. Please read what was edited before reverting, or please mention the _correct_ reason. The edit didn't remove the seek at all, but you're saying it did.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that is the way it works.  Your examples aren't quite the same, though.  Your first example reads from 10000, then 10001, then 10002, etc.  The second needs a seek outside the loop to set the initial position.  To be 100% equivalent, you need to have your second example look like:

```
cpos=10000;
dataFile.seekg(cpos,ios::beg);
for (i=0;i<20;i++) {
   dataFile.read(carray[i],1);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I know that -- I was merely demonstrating the non-seeking in the loop. Thanks for the confirmation.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the file pointer is automatically moved by read and write operations. ...and **not** seeking **improves** the performance **a lot**. Also, using `file.read(ptr, 20)` is a lot faster than using 20 times `file.read(ptr + i, 1)`. To get the same semantics, you'll need to navigate to the appropriate location, though, using one seek.

Seeking in a file stream sets the stream into a state where it can continue to both read or write characters: To switch between reading and writing for a stream opened in read/write mode (`std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::out`) it is necessary to introduce a seek. Each see, thus, set the available buffer up in a funny way which the stream doesn't need to do if it just reads or writes a sequence of characters. Also, when writing each seek at least checks whether it is necessary to write characters to get into an initial state for code conversion.

Comment: How your answer would be different if it were `std::ifstream` or `std::ofstream`, not `std::fstream`? Is it a big difference?

Comment: It sure does. Back in the day around Unix System 7 I *doubled* the speed of I/O by removing redundant `seek()` calls.

Comment: @starriet: the logic happens on `streambuf` level which could dynamically know whether the stream is opened read/write and might optimize things. I doubt that would be done, though.