# How to read file from last cursor position?

Tags: c++

```
char buf[100];
int bufSize = 100;
int lastPosition = 0;
while(!myfile.eof()){
myfile.read(buf,100);
myfile.seekg(lastPosition);
lastPosition = lastPosition + bufSize;
}
```

I try to read 100 bytes from myfile and set the cursor position 100. byte. Then I want to read from 100. byte to 200. byte ... till the end of file. What I'm doing is true?

Comment: You don't even need to use `seekg`, the cursor position will advance on its own when you read from the file. If you read bytes `0` to `99` (so, 100 bytes), the cursor will end at position `100` already.

Comment: So the last two lines in while are unnecessary? @Nbr44

Comment: Exactly. If you keep only `myfile.read(buf, 100)` in your loop, it will properly take care of reading all your file, `100` bytes after `100` bytes (unless, of course, you have something like `435` bytes in your file, the last read would be of size `35`in that case).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume `myfile` is an `istream`.

In this case, this is not exactly the way it works:

- `read()` moves the file pointer when reading, so no need to `seek()` every time
- the loop you have provided as an example overwrites the buffer each time a chunck is read, without doing anything with it

You should either try something like this:

```
char buf[100];
int bufSize = 100;

while(!myfile.eof()){
    myfile.read(buf, bufSize);
    // do something with your chunck here.        
}
```

Or like this:

```
char * theWholeFile;
int pos = 0;
int chunckSize = 100; 

theWholeFile = new char[myfile.tellg()];

while(!myfile.eof()){
    myfile.read(theWholeFile + pos, chunckSize);
    pos += chunckSize; 
}    

// theWholeFile contains the whole file at that point. Don't forget to delete it at some point!
```

I did not handle the last chunck here. Its size can be anything between 0 and 100. You can use `myfile.tellg() % chunckSize` to determine its actual size (for example).

For further details, have a look at this [related question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14148238/does-fstream-read-write-move-file-pointer).

Answer (score 0):

```
int fileParts = 30;
int bufSize = 100;
char buf[fileParts}[bufSize];
int i = 0;
while(!myfile.eof() && i<fileParts){
      myfile.read(buf[i],100);
      ++i;
}
```

Or use vector of byte arrays instead of two dimensional array.