# Why std::istream::read moves the file pointer NOT according to bytes read

Tags: c++, fstream

I'm [std::istream::read](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/read/) move the file pointer according to the file pointer (as stated here [does fstream read/write move file pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14148238/1798187))

I have this innocent looking piece of code:

```
void SomeClass::read(__in uint32_t& Res)
{
    std::fstream ifInput(pathSrc.string().c_str());
    if (ifInput.fail())
    {
        LOG_ERROR(L"couldn't read file " << pathSrc.string().c_str());
        return;
    }

    m_Stream = &ifInput;

    cout << m_Stream->tellg() << endl;
    Res = 0;
    char cBuffer[4];
    m_Stream->read(&cBuffer[0], 4); 
    if (m_Stream->fail())
        return;

    cout << m_Stream->tellg() << endl;
}
```

Oddly, I get this output:

```
0
3588 <<<<<< why not 4?
```

Any idea why is that?

Comment: Why are you storing a pointer to a local into `m_Stream`? You know that the `fstream` object is destructed at the end of the method, right? And that the pointer will point to an invalid object?

Comment: I posted and edited version of my class to avoid having to post members and other functions. 10x.

Comment: You probably mean `read(cBuffer, 4);` instead of `read(&cBuffer[0], 4);`

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ In this context those are the same thing. (The array will decay into a pointer.)

Comment: How long is your file?

Comment: @idanshmu I'm not sure how that is relevant to my point that you shouldn't be storing pointers to method locals in class-level fields.

Comment: [I can't reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ed0ac3ee47599b46). What compiler are you using?

Comment: @cdhowie `m_Stream` is a member of the class and it is not initialized in the posted function. the file itself is opened outside of this function as well. I "corrupted" my function a little just for the sake of the question. I didn't think the changes are relevant for the issue but if you think otherwise I'd be happy to edit the question.

Comment: @Anton Savin using vsc++2013

Comment: @idanshmu I'm getting the same result (`0 4`) with my code on VS2013 as well (file aaa.txt is 4 bytes "abcd").

Comment: Maybe you can post the actual code without modifications?

Comment: Have you tested that the problem persists with your modifications? Also, what are the contents of your file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was due to this line:

```
std::fstream ifInput(pathSrc.string().c_str());
```

The file I was reading was partially binary, so:

```
std::fstream ifInput(pathSrc.string().c_str(), std::fstream::in | std::fstream::binary);
```

resolved the issues.